# Cannot append pixel buffer into AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor randomly

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession, avassetwriter, cmsamplebuffer

I'm using `AVAssetWriter` and `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` to add mask image into `CMSampleBuffer` which recorded from `AVCaptureSession`, but sometimes I got this error when try to append processed `pixelBuffer` to `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor`:

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could
>   not be completed" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x170845af0 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16364 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16364),
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=XXXXDEFAULTVALUEXXXX,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed}

Comment: do you have a small project that reproduces this problem?

Comment: I found the problem, I was using the a concurrent queue when edit the output `CMSampleBuffer`, thx